# undefined method `each' do Subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined

I am getting the following undefined method `each` error. 
I am following along with the exercises on [Lynda](http://lynda.com) and I am stuck here. I have attempted to understand the solutions in the other questions but its still beyond my understanding. any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass): 
    10:             <th>Pages</th>
    11:             <th>Actions</th>
    12:         </tr>
    13:         <% @Subjects.each do|subject| %>
    14:         <tr>
    15:             <td><%= subject.position %></td>
    16:             <td><%= subject.name %></td>
  app/views/subjects/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_subjects_index_html_erb__3548269486732453408_70351994996820'
```

Here is the index code that is defined in `models/views/subjects/index.html.erb`

```
<div class = "subjects index">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>
  <%= link_to("Add New Subject",'#', :class => 'action new') %>

  <table class ="listing" summary ="Subject list">
    <tr class = "header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @Subjects.each do|subject| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= subject.position %></td>
        <td><%= subject.name %></td>
        <td class ="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
        <td class = "center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
        <td class = "action">
          <%= link_to("Show", '#',:class => 'action show') %>
          <%= link_to("Edit", '#' ,:class => 'action edit') %>
          <%= link_to("Delete", '#',:class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Subject model is as follows:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages

  scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
  scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("subjects.position ASC") }
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("subjects.created_at DESC")}
  scope :search, lambda {|query|
    where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
  }

end
```

when i type Subject.all

```
irb(main):001:0> Subject.all
  Subject Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `subjects`.* FROM `subjects`
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Subject id: 1, name: "Initial Subject", position: 1, visible: true, created_at: "2015-04-28 04:11:54", updated_at: "2015-04-28 04:18:58">, #<Subject id: 2, name: "Revised Subject", position: 2, visible: true, created_at: "2015-04-28 04:15:01", updated_at: "2015-04-28 04:22:12">, #<Subject id: 4, name: "Third Subject", position: 3, visible: false, created_at: "2015-04-28 04:31:04", updated_at: "2015-04-28 04:31:04">]>
```

Comment: Your instance variable `@Subjects` is uppercase. It would be `@subjects`.

Comment: Add controller code also.

Comment: thank you that fixed the issue. however, another one arises. 
this time, it is `undefined method `name'`
yet highlighting this line 
`<td class = "center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>`
if someone can explain why this happening, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: when I replaced `.size`  with `.count`. 
it has worked. not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Subjects` is uppercase so this is empty. Also please check first `@subjects.present?` before loop through each.